# Sharing R library's between linux subsystem for windows and windows

Tags: r, windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a window ubuntu VM.  I have R installed in the windows.  I recently tried to call an R script in my ubuntu but it told me the library is not installed.  Is there a way to tell ubuntu's R installation to use my windows R libraries so I don't have to reinstall them all on ubuntu?

```
StratifiedFullModel/SecondRun$ Rscript StratifiedFullModels.R
Loading required package: car
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages(x, dependencies = TRUE) :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages(x, dependencies = TRUE) :
  unable to install packages
Calls: lapply -> FUN -> install.packages
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘car’
Execution halted
```

This is strange because the script is set up to check for packages, one of which is car, and either load them or install them.  I suspect it is not doing so because of some problem with permissions.

This is problematic because I may want to write scripts that just auto install packages without me having to manually do it which would be time consuming if I share a script with a colleague or if I transfer work to a new machine.

**Edit:** Tried turing R on in ubuntu and running install.packages("car") returned the following error:

```
> install.packages("car")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("car") :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel) cancel
Error in install.packages("car") : unable to install packages
>
```

I just cancelled the install.  I think this confirms my suspicion that there is an issue with the permissions.

Comment: Have you tried  `chmod 700 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library` to give write access?

Comment: (1) Having "libraries" shared between different operating systems is generally not feasible. While not all of R's packages have truly "compiled" shared libraries, I don't think sharing them is feasible. (2) *"auto install packages ... share a script with a colleague"*, this is the true dilemma that *reproducible research* is intended to mitigate. Asking to share libraries between *your* windows and *your* linux does nothing to address sharing with colleagues, this is a different question. (3) That `install.packages` error is very clear, use a personal library. Have you tried that?

Comment: `Would you like to use a personal library instead? (yes/No/cancel) cancel` don't cancel

Comment: I cancelled on purpose the question is not about that.  Its about how to get a script to do it.  I wanted to see if there was a permissions problem by manually installing car

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux and Windows installations of R are completely separate, and that includes packages. That said, you can run the Windows version from within WSL, so you don't need to maintain duplicate environments.

Here's a screenshot of both Linux and Windows R running on my machine, from within WSL:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Note that this answer is based on my experience with WSL rather than R specifically.  I'd welcome updates or more authoritative answers from anyone who has used R under WSL.

I believe you are going to run into problems if you attempt to use, at least, *some* Windows R libraries from WSL.  A 'pure-R' library should work, in theory, but it looks to me from some quick searches that R can also include compiled code which would be platform-specific.  In this case, if any libraries end up in native-code, then a Windows library is going to have issues when called from Linux with Linux path structures (e.g. `/home` instead of `C:\Users`), processes, and other OS constructs.

As for the permissions issue, R is using a default library directory (under `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`) that is only writable by `root`.  It appears that you can change the library installation directory with something like:

```
> install.packages("car", lib="/home/<username>/.local/lib/R/site-library/")
```

Of course, you'll need to create that directory first.  See [this page](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2010/11/installing-r-packages/) for more details.